# Correct destruction process for async code running in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, destruction

Below is (working) code for a generic websocket streamer.

It creates a daemon thread from which performs `asyncio.run(...)`.

The asyncio code spawns 2 tasks, which never complete.

How to correctly destroy this object?

One of the tasks is executing a keepalive 'ping', so I can easily exit that loop using a flag. But the other is blocking on a message from the websocket.

```
import json
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import gzip

import asyncio
from threading import Thread

class WebSocket:
    KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_S = 10

    def __init__(self, url, on_connect, on_msg):
        self.url = url
        self.on_connect = on_connect
        self.on_msg = on_msg

        self.streams = {}
        self.worker_thread = Thread(name='WebSocket', target=self.thread_func, daemon=True).start()

    def thread_func(self):
        asyncio.run(self.aio_run())

    async def aio_run(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

            self.ws = await session.ws_connect(self.url)

            await self.on_connect(self)

            async def ping():
                while True:
                    print('KEEPALIVE')
                    await self.ws.ping()
                    await asyncio.sleep(WebSocket.KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_S)

            async def main_loop():
                async for msg in self.ws:
                    def extract_data(msg):
                        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.BINARY:
                            as_bytes = gzip.decompress(msg.data)
                            as_string = as_bytes.decode('utf8')
                            as_json = json.loads(as_string)
                            return as_json

                        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
                            return json.loads(msg.data)

                        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
                            print('⛔️ aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR')

                        return msg.data

                    data = extract_data(msg)

                    self.on_msg(data)

            # May want this approach if we want to handle graceful shutdown
            # W.task_ping = asyncio.create_task(ping())
            # W.task_main_loop = asyncio.create_task(main_loop())

            await asyncio.gather(
                ping(),
                main_loop()
            )

    async def send_json(self, J):
        await self.ws.send_json(J)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the use of [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) instead of `asyncio.run`. It returns a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object which you can cancel:

```py
def thread_func(self):
    self.future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
        self.aio_run(), 
        asyncio.get_event_loop()
    )

# somewhere else
self.future.cancel()
```

Another approach would be to make `ping` and `main_loop` a task, and cancel them when necessary:

```py
# inside `aio_run`
self.task_ping = asyncio.create_task(ping())
self.main_loop_task = asyncio.create_task(main_loop())

await asyncio.gather(
    self.task_ping,
    self.main_loop_task
    return_exceptions=True
)


# somewhere else
self.task_ping.cancel()
self.main_loop_task.cancel()
```

This doesn't change the fact that `aio_run` should also be called with `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`. `asyncio.run` should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs and should be only called once.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest one more variation of the solution. When finishing coroutines (tasks), I prefer minimizing the use of `cancel()` (but not excluding), since sometimes it can make it difficult to debug business logic (keep in mind that `asyncio.CancelledError` does not inherit from an `Exception`).

In your case, the code might look like this(only changes):

```
class WebSocket:
    KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_S = 10

    def __init__(self, url, on_connect, on_msg):
        # ...      
        self.worker_thread = Thread(name='WebSocket', target=self.thread_func)
        self.worker_thread.start()

    async def aio_run(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        # ...
 
        self._ping_task = asyncio.create_task(ping())
        self._main_task = asyncio.create_task(main_loop())

        await asyncio.gather(
            self._ping_task,
            self._main_task,
            return_exceptions=True
        )
        # ...

    async def stop_ping(self):
        self._ping_task.cancel()
        try:
            await self._ping_task
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass

    async def _stop(self):
        # wait ping end before socket closing
        await self.stop_ping()
        # lead to correct exit from `async for msg in self.ws`
        await self.ws.close()

    def stop(self):
        # wait stopping ping and closing socket
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            self._stop(), self._loop
        ).result() 
        self.worker_thread.join()  # wait thread finish
```